# Receive Parse.push.send using cloud function succeed but device not receiving push notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I tried to use `Parse.push.send` with cloud function I define to send out a push notification to a device. I follow the guide on CodePath [Guide](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Configuring-a-Parse-Server) and I receive a success call back in my iOS App. However, none of the remote notification was delivered. I also have the `_p_installationKey` in my `_User` collection, and I can verify that the `_Installation` collection also have an entry matching the address stored in the `_User` collection. For each cloud function I call, one `_PushStatus` entry will be inserted, but numSent is 0.  Below are the collections stored in my  MLab and my environment.

## _PushStatus

```
{
    "_id": "3mxSHXoZa0",
    "pushTime": "2017-05-19T17:38:46.346Z",
    "query": "{\"deviceType\":\"ios\"}",
    "payload": "{\"alert\":\"Message: Testing\"}",
    "source": "rest",
    "status": "running",
    "numSent": 0,
    "pushHash": "424b520d52c5e20b4eb95be535cb2d54",
    "_wperm": [],
    "_rperm": [],
    "_acl": {},
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-05-19T17:38:46.346Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-05-19T17:38:46.408Z"
    },
    "count": 1
}
```

## _Installation

```
{
    "_id": "EMZ8EUmrC6",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "deviceToken": "55097f4ceca541cc5b02b5852d96d10c8238f147c3ec53c3e8a44bfc66520e41",
    "deviceType": "ios",
    "appVersion": "1",
    "appName": "myAppName",
    "channels": [
        "global"
    ],
    "installationId": "ae540abe-21d4-446f-b90f-f5b6bec04109",
    "appIdentifier": "myAppIdentifier",
    "parseVersion": "1.14.2",
    "localeIdentifier": "en-US",
    "badge": 0,
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-05-19T06:03:14.614Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-05-19T06:03:14.614Z"
    }
}
```

## _User

```
{
    "_id": "ZEMtqdJMaw",
    "_p_installationKey": "_Installation$EMZ8EUmrC6",
    "username": "121259958664",
    "_hashed_password": "$2a$10$HR6TtUFB5G3tkeA9LlHbvuKOE2rpG.gvyHqAjsOQBps.X9jQvu9DO",
    "_wperm": [
        "ZEMtqdJMaw"
    ],
    "_rperm": [
        "*",
        "ZEMtqdJMaw"
    ],
    "_acl": {
        "ZEMtqdJMaw": {
            "w": true,
            "r": true
        },
        "*": {
            "r": true
        }
    },
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2017-05-19T06:03:27.637Z"
    },
    "_updated_at": {
        "$date": "2017-05-19T06:03:27.637Z"
    }
}
```

## Config Vars in Heroku

[image]

## main.js

```
// iOS push testing
Parse.Cloud.define("iosPushTest", function(request, response) {

  // request has 2 parameters: params passed by the client and the authorized user                                                                                                                               
  var params = request.params;
  var user = request.user;

  // Our "Message" class has a "text" key with the body of the message itself                                                                                                                                    
  var messageText = params.text;

  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo('deviceType', 'ios'); // targeting iOS devices only                                                                                                                                          

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query                                                                                                                                                              
    data: {
      alert: "Message: " + messageText
    }
  }, { success: function() {
      console.log("#### PUSH OK");
      response.success('success');

  }, error: function(error) {
      console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
     response.error('failed');
  }, useMasterKey: true});
});
```

## index.js

```
var devCertPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ParsePushDevelopmentCertificate.p12');

var pushConfig = {'ios': [
  {
   pfx: devCertPath, // P12 file only
   bundleId: 'myBundleId',  // change to match bundleId
   production: false // dev certificate
  }
 ]
};


var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
  push: pushConfig
});
```

## Logs

```
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:04.498577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:04.498577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:04.498578+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:04.498579+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:06:04.498579+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:04.501023+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:06:04.501397+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:04 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:04.501480+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:04 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:04.501686+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:06:04.501787+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:04 GMT apn 1 left to send
2017-05-19T18:06:20.502222+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Initialising connection
2017-05-19T18:06:20.502541+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn 1 left to send
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611635+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Socket error occurred undefined { Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611652+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611653+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611654+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611655+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611802+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Destroying connection undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:20.611886+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612721+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Raising error: { Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612723+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612724+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612724+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612725+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612725+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612726+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612727+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' } undefined undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612870+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Error occurred with trace: Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612871+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612872+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612872+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612873+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612873+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612874+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.612875+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:06:20.613192+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:06:20.613647+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:20.613741+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:20.624646+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:06:20.624800+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:20 GMT apn 1 left to send
2017-05-19T18:06:52.614568+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Initialising connection
2017-05-19T18:06:52.614810+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn 1 left to send
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758861+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Socket error occurred undefined { Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758864+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758865+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758866+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758866+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758867+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.758869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759154+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Destroying connection undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759277+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759717+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Raising error: { Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759719+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759721+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759722+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759722+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759723+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' } undefined undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759875+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Error occurred with trace: Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759876+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759877+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759880+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759880+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.760240+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:06:52.760741+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.760851+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.761152+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:06:52.761244+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn 1 left to send
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759877+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759880+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.759880+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:06:52.760240+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:06:52.760741+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.760851+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:06:52.761152+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:06:52.761244+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:06:52 GMT apn 1 left to send
2017-05-19T18:07:42.422486+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/push" host=spottune.herokuapp.com request_id=4ebb4912-b4d5-42bd-8057-21cb23763300 fwd="54.204.64.16" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=533 protocol=https
2017-05-19T18:07:42.368169+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/functions/iosPushTest: {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.368182+00:00 app[web.1]:   "text": "Testing"
2017-05-19T18:07:42.368186+00:00 app[web.1]: } method=POST, url=/parse/functions/iosPushTest, host=myapp.herokuapp.com, connection=close, x-parse-app-display-version=1.0, x-parse-application-id=applicationID, accept=*/*, accept-language=en-us, x-parse-os-version=10.3.2 (14F5080a), user-agent=Spottunes/1 CFNetwork/811.5.3 Darwin/16.6.0, x-parse-app-build-version=1, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, x-parse-session-token=r:d574da7c3405de7c7cad42c147bcec85, x-parse-client-version=i1.14.2, x-parse-installation-id=ae540abe-21d4-446f-b90f-f5b6bec04109, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, x-request-id=1d2c625e-2d55-4270-b9b0-9b3c74ea457d, x-forwarded-for=128.54.116.32, x-forwarded-proto=https, x-forwarded-port=443, via=1.1 vegur, connect-time=0, x-request-start=1495217262279, total-route-time=0, content-length=18, text=Testing
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409208+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/push: {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409211+00:00 app[web.1]:   "where": {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409212+00:00 app[web.1]:     "deviceType": "ios"
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409213+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409214+00:00 app[web.1]:   "data": {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409214+00:00 app[web.1]:     "alert": "Message: Testing"
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409215+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2017-05-19T18:07:42.409218+00:00 app[web.1]: } method=POST, url=/parse/push, host=myapp.herokuapp.com, connection=close, user-agent=node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.9.2 (NodeJS 7.10.0), accept=*/*, content-type=text/plain, x-request-id=4ebb4912-b4d5-42bd-8057-21cb23763300, x-forwarded-for=54.204.64.16, x-forwarded-proto=https, x-forwarded-port=443, via=1.1 vegur, connect-time=0, x-request-start=1495217262403, total-route-time=0, content-length=237, deviceType=ios, alert=Message: Testing
2017-05-19T18:07:42.410004+00:00 app[web.1]: [33mwarn[39m: Trying to schedule a push while server is not configured.
2017-05-19T18:07:42.410267+00:00 app[web.1]: [33mwarn[39m: Push will be sent immediately
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420038+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/push: {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420040+00:00 app[web.1]:   "headers": {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420041+00:00 app[web.1]:     "X-Parse-Push-Status-Id": "OBtnkjGpL8"
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420042+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420043+00:00 app[web.1]:   "response": {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420043+00:00 app[web.1]:     "result": true
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420044+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2017-05-19T18:07:42.420044+00:00 app[web.1]: } X-Parse-Push-Status-Id=OBtnkjGpL8, result=true
2017-05-19T18:07:42.428718+00:00 app[web.1]: #### PUSH OK
2017-05-19T18:07:42.429322+00:00 app[web.1]: [32minfo[39m: Ran cloud function iosPushTest for user ZEMtqdJMaw with:
2017-05-19T18:07:42.429324+00:00 app[web.1]:   Input: {"text":"Testing"}
2017-05-19T18:07:42.429325+00:00 app[web.1]:   Result: "success" functionName=iosPushTest, text=Testing, user=ZEMtqdJMaw
2017-05-19T18:07:42.430053+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/functions/iosPushTest: {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.430054+00:00 app[web.1]:   "response": {
2017-05-19T18:07:42.430055+00:00 app[web.1]:     "result": "success"
2017-05-19T18:07:42.430056+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2017-05-19T18:07:42.430056+00:00 app[web.1]: } result=success
2017-05-19T18:07:42.433082+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: _PushStatus OBtnkjGpL8: sending push to 1 installations
2017-05-19T18:07:42.458687+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:42 GMT apn 2 left to send
2017-05-19T18:07:42.432839+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/functions/iosPushTest" host=spottune.herokuapp.com request_id=1d2c625e-2d55-4270-b9b0-9b3c74ea457d fwd="128.54.116.32" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=151ms status=200 bytes=502 protocol=https
2017-05-19T18:07:56.765036+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:56 GMT apn Initialising connection
2017-05-19T18:07:56.767442+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:56 GMT apn 2 left to send
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045303+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Socket error occurred undefined { Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045317+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045318+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045318+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045319+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045319+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045320+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045320+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045416+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Destroying connection undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045473+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045796+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Raising error: { Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045797+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045797+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045798+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045798+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045799+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045799+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' } undefined undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045910+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Error occurred with trace: Error: socket hang up
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045912+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045912+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045913+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045915+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045916+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046198+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046589+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046677+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046816+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046889+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn 2 left to send
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045912+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045913+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045915+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045916+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046198+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046589+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046677+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046816+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046889+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn 2 left to send
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045912+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045913+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045915+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.045916+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046198+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Socket Error
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046589+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Socket closed undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046677+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn Removing socket from pool undefined
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046816+00:00 app[web.1]: verb parse-server-push-adapter APNS APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
2017-05-19T18:07:57.046889+00:00 app[web.1]: Fri, 19 May 2017 18:07:57 GMT apn 2 left to send
```

## Call using Swift

```
 print("sending push notification...")
  let param: [String: Any] = [
  "text" : "Testing"
    ]

    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "iosPushTest", withParameters:  param) { (response, error) in
         print("push \(response)")
     }
```

## Xcode console

```
sending push notification...
push Optional(success)
```

Not sure what else should I add in order to make this work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps since parse is a discontinued product it would be a good Idea to update to firebase for example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a file path to your APNS cert in your configs. That needs to be included, and there is a little bit of extra configuration to do in your index.js to enable Push. Not sure how it's hadnled when you call Push.send() without the extra configuration enabled, but that looks to be going through. So, my bet is invalid APNS. If you debug this locally, you'd likely get some more useful server output.